Why does Leaflet create multiple pages
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import L from 'leaflet';
  import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-map',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './map.component.html',
    styleUrl: './map.component.css'
  })
  export class MapComponent {
  private index = 0;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

      this.index++;
  console.log(this.index)
      L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    }

  }

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MapComponent, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <main>
      <a [routerLink]="['/']">
        <header class="brand-name">
        </header>
      </a>
      <section class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </section>
    </main>
  `,
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'homes';

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  //console.log(this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl));
  }
}

It is a very simple code with a mapcomponent and a appcomponent. I do not have any idea what happens.
Honestty, I do not undersand what happens. I followed the tutorial of leaflet. There are nothing more, any component, I just created a project with npm new and created a component with ng generate.


please share the tutorial followed, what is wrong in the screenshot, expectedoutput, if possible a working stackblitz, what do you mean by multiple pages?

I changed the line L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' to L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png', and I have the same problem.  I do not have any error in the console. I have the the problem in Edge and Chrome. I followed this tutorial : https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/. Thanks you very much

Getting started with Leaflet for Angular:
First install the dependencies (leaflet base package and @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet which is an angular wrapper for leaflet:
npm install leaflet
npm install @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet

After installing the dependencies, you have to add the css and js file of leaflet to angular.json:
          "options": {
            "assets": [],
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "src/global_styles.css"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"
          }

After this is done, you are ready to use leaflet, so the base code will be to import leaflet types and LeafletModule which contains the directive and other required parts to the imports array of the standalone component, if you want to use modular approach, add to the imports array of the respective NgModule.
import { LeafletDirective, LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { tileLayer, latLng } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [LeafletModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div style="height: 300px;"
      leaflet 
      [leafletOptions]="options">
    </div>  
  `,
})

After this, we can define in the HTML, a div element with the directive leaflet along with the input options [leafletOptions], as shown above.
We can then declare the options in the component and then take a ViewChild of LeafletDirective which contains the leaflet element, then access the map property and set the location to show on the map.
export class App {
  @ViewChild(LeafletDirective) leaflet!: LeafletDirective;
  private index = 0;
  options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      }),
    ],
    zoom: 5,
    center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909),
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.leaflet);
    this.leaflet.map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LeafletDirective, LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { tileLayer, latLng } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [LeafletModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        <div style="height: 300px;"
          leaflet 
          [leafletOptions]="options">
        </div>  
      `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(LeafletDirective) leaflet!: LeafletDirective;
  private index = 0;
  options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      }),
    ],
    zoom: 5,
    center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909),
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.leaflet);
    this.leaflet.map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

F... tutorial
It is written {z}/{x}/{y}, but it is (so logically) {x}/{y}/{z}.
So much time lost :(
Thanks for your time

I think it's {z}/{x}/{y}, could find plenty of examples using this format, please recheck the code.
